# Python Matplotlib draw an image without a background on top of another image on Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 images (the first is a single-band float32 image, the second is an RGB uint8 image, both images are the same size):

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

I want to place image 2 on top of image 1 in such a way that the black color in image 2 becomes transparent, and the red color, on the contrary, is displayed.

How can this be done via MatplotLib?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the matrix manipulation methods to blend your images where certain conditions are met.

E.g:

```
img3=np.where(img2 < 10 , img1, img2)
```

That would create a new image where the everyhwere where the value of img2 is lower then 10 it replaces it with the value of img1

The only thing is that the images must have the same size or at least the value can be broadcasted to be the same size.

(np is numpy)

If you have the one as uint and the other as float32 you should convert the one first. From looking at your images it seems both are basically single channel anyway so i would convert the RGB one to a single channel as well:

E.g. with something like:

```
  img_bw= img_rgb @ [0.33,0.33,0.33] / 255.0
```

To convert them from int to float with an average of all 3 color channels and a float range of 0.0 to 1.0

Alternatively you can also use the different color channels to represent the different source images in the final image..

Another option is to use the alpha option on imshow when you show an image.

```
  plt.imshow(img1)
  plt.imshow(img2,alpha=np.where(img2 < 10,1.0,0.0))
```